# How to apply different styles to rows in a QML TreeView

Tags: qml, treeview

I have a requirement to display a treeview in QML. The data looks like this

```
title item
    sub item
    sub item
title item
    sub item
```

What I need to do is to display a check box next to all title items but not the sub items

I have managed to get a check box for all items but I dont know how to only have it displayed for title items

```js
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TreeView {
        model: myModel

        alternatingRowColors: false
        anchors.fill: parent

        headerDelegate: {
            visible: false
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            title: "Name"
            role: "display"
            width: 300
        }

        itemDelegate: Item {
            id: itemId

            CheckBox {
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                text: styleData.value.text
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can do something like `CheckBox{ visible: !!modelData.is_title ... }` or `CheckBox { visible: !modelData.is_subheader }` . You have to do the double inversion (`!!`), because QML doesn't quite follow javascript truthiness rules.  `undefined` throws an error when assigned to `visible` instead of just evaluating to `false`.

Comment: Ok Thanks - What if I need to implement an itemDelegate that displays different components dependant upon the model data?

Comment: To switch different components, use a [`Loader`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html).  `Loader { source: modelData.is_title ? FooComponent : BarComponent }` .  You can make [`Components` without creating a new file by using the `Component` keyword.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html)

Comment: I'll try that, but what is modelData? is this something I return from the C++ model? Also what if I have a more than 1 type of component (means I cant use ternary operator)

Comment: Ooops.  `modelData` is a copy or a reference of the current element when doing a [`Repeater`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater-members.html).  So, whatever your reference or copy of your data is called, that's what you would use as your determinant.

Comment: Ah Ok - what about selecting from a set of components, meaning that I cant use a ternary statement?

Comment: Well.... I have used massively nested ternary statements for the `source:` field. `source: modelData.is_title ? Foo : ( modelData.is_awesome? Bar : Baz)` .  I think you _could_ put it in a function, but then QML might not get the dependency graph right and then not re-evaluate the `source` attribute if one of the ternary determinants changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested I think this is the correct way of doing this

```
    itemDelegate: Loader {
        property string imageSource: model.imageSource
        property string title: model.title
        property int fontSize: model.fontSize
        property string subText: model.subText
        source: {
            switch (model.type)
            {
            case 0:
                return "TopLevelComponent.qml"
            case 1:
                return "StationComponent.qml"
            case 2:
                return "StationComponent.qml"
            }
```